# C# Interfaces & Dependency Injection

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand a little more about interface injection and how it all hangs together.

My system has different types of users. Each user will see a different set of menu on the home page. Rather than having a big switch statement checking the type of user & load menu accordingly, I created a "User" base class and the derived classes implement the IMenu interface. But on `Page_Load()`, I still need to know the type of `User` to create before I can call the `LoadMenu()` method. My question is, how can I get away from hard-coding the instantiation of a type of `User` object?  Or even when I retrieve the data from DB and create a type of `User` object, I still need to check the type of user and use `switch`. Is there a way to get away from that?

Below is my code

```
//base class
Public class User {
    private string _Username;
    Private string _Name;
}


Public Interface IMenu {
    void LoadMenu();
}

Public class Manager : User, IMenu {
     public override void LoadMenu(){
         //loads manager's menu
     }
}

public class Employee: User, IMenu {
     public override void LoadMenu(){
         //loads employee's menu
     }
}


protected void Page_Load() {
     //Retrieve user details from database
     //Instantiate an object of derived `User` type.
     //Call `LoadMenu()` method.
}
```

Comment: Do you really need multiple types of user? Unless there is another reason, I'd stick with using role based access and assign users to the roles they need.

Comment: If you really need different types of users, then to really follow good OOD, you should have a class for each type of user derived from a more generic user base class. If you are talking about the authorization each user has, then a role based system as DavidG mentioned would be a better choice.

Comment: AFAIK you should define abstractions (interfaces) for *behaviour*, not for *data*.

Comment: You're trying to implement the Strategy Pattern.  Looking at some simple examples should help you out.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. @DavidG @Nick Zimmerman , how would a role based access help me move away from having a `switch` statement checking the role of the user and load menu accordingly?

Comment: Well there are many frameworks out there that will build your menu based on the roles available for that user. For example MVC has MVCSiteMap.

Comment: @Maarten thanks for that. Noted. Just for my understanding and let's say `LoadMenu()` is behaviour, how can I get away from my original problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue with the switch statement is. Sooner or later you will always have to decide what `IUser` or `IMenuLoader`, etc. you need to build based on user's data stored in the db (access lever, role, etc.) Dependency injection is not about avoiding switch statements, its about avoiding dependencies and making your architecture as decoupled as possible. That is achieved normally through interfaces and the factory method pattern. If in the future you need a new access level, you would only need to update the `MenuLoaderFactory` without touching anything else.

Comment: @InBetween Thanks for clarifying. I've been wondering how to achieve DI when instantiating an object based on data from DB. Do you have any a simple "end-to-end" example of how to create objects from DB and apply DI on that object?  I don't mean there's anything wrong with switch statement but if I can get away with not using it and just let the complier determine which method implementation to call, that is a win.

Comment: What is the question here? In this scenario there are two questions: 1.How to use DI in this system? 2. What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use dependency injection to load different types that adhere to a common interface, you should look into [typed factories](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) (at least that's how it is called in [castle-windsor](/questions/tagged/castle-windsor) - the same concept should be found in other frameworks)

The principle is the following: you have an interface which returns the common interface you're interested in

```
public interface IUserFactory {
    IUser GetUser(string userType);
}
```

Then you register all your types deriving from the common interface you want to resolve, with a discriminating information; it can be the type of the class, or some other information.

Finally you inform the factory about the link between the types that have been registered and the discriminating information; for example if we had used the class type as the name of a component in a windsor factory, then we could tell the factory that a request for `IUser` should be resolved by using the parameter we pass it as the component name. In Windsor this can done by inheriting from `DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector`

```
public class CustomTypedFactoryComponentSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    protected override string GetComponentName(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
        if(method.Name == "GetUser" && arguments.Length == 1 && arguments[0] is string)
        {
            return (string)arguments[0];
        }
        return base.GetComponentName(method, arguments);
    }
}
```

You would then get something like

```
var dbUser = DB.LoadUser(1234);
IUser user = IUserFactory.GetUser(dbUser.Type);
user.LoadMenu();
```

---

As a matter of style, I'd recommend not giving a user the responsibility to load the menu; instead you would perhaps be in a better place if the menu was loaded by passing it the user, or even best an interface that describes authorized actions. This way you can load a menu for a user, but the menu is not limited by it and be loaded for machines, groups, etc... This is architecture country, so I won't stray any further but the comments under your question are good pointers :)

Comment: One thing to note, using the current interface, you'd need to cast user to IMenu to LoadMenu such as: `IMenu userMenu = user as IMenu;
    if (userMenu != null) { userMenu.LoadMenu() }`

Comment: @AWinkle I was making an assumption that IUser would contain the LoadMenu method, hence my last point where I recommend not loading the menu from the user but rather loading the menu by passing it the user _or_ a correct abstraction (`IHaveCredentials` could be a good name :) )

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bewildered with your concept that avoiding switch statements is equivalent to dependency injection. Sooner or later you need to place the logic of what to do with your application's menu depending on your current user.

Dependency injection is about decoupling as much as possible your arquitecture from the logic of that decision, not avoiding it. If done right, even if in the future that logic changes you don't need to rewrite half your code.

I don't know if I would do it the way you are planning, but based on your approach, I'd do something similar to the following (thought up really fast so its bound to have holes in it, but you should get the idea):

```
public enum UserAccessLevel
{
    None,
    Employee,
    Manager
}

public interface IUser
{
     string Name { get; }
     string UserName { get; }
     UserAccessLevel AccessLevel { get; }
}

public interface IMenuLoader
{
     void LoadMenu()
}

public class MenuLoaderFactory()
{
     public IMenuLoader GetMenuLoader(UserAccesLevel accesLevel)
     {
         IMenuLoader menuLoader = null;

         switch (accesLevel)
         {
             case UserAccessLevel.Employee
                  menuLoader = new EmployeeMenuLoader();
                  break;
             case UserAccessLevel.Manager
                  menuLoader = new ManagerMenuLoader();
         }

         return menuLoader ;   
     }
}

public sealed class EmployeeMenuLoader: IMenuLoader {...}
public sealed class ManagerMenuLoader: IMenuLoader {...}
```

Now in you main page you should only hold references to IUser, IMenuLoader. If in a few months, you decide to add a new access level, all the plumbing is still valid. You'd only need to create the new `MenuLoader` class and update the logic in the `MenuLoaderFactory` and `UserLevelAccess` Enum (on second though I'd probably get rid of this enum) to take into account the new access and your set.

Comment: Can you kindly explain what `public IMenuLoad(UserAccessLevel accessLevel){}' means? A constructor of type `IMenuLoader` interface?

Comment: @user3860564: oops, sorry typo.